# Compare two files in linux and output difference only in 2nd file

Tags: linux, unix, compare, diff

I want a unix command to Compare 2 text files and output the difference found only in 2nd text file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Give us examples of both text files. Show us what you did and what you expect ?

Comment: As above, and  please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: abc.txt  contains 3 lines 111,222,333   def.txt contains 3 lines 111,444,222  ... I tried this command this gives difference in both files diff -a --suppress-common-lines -y abc.txt def.txt

Comment: Usually you'd use the `comm` command for this. If you must use `diff`, can you give us the exact text of your assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

$ diff /tmp/file1.txt /tmp/file2.txt